# Find the value $a$ that make the function is continuous:

Tags: limits, continuity

Find the value $a$ that make the function is continuous:

$$
f(x,y,z)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{x^2yz^2}{x^6+y^4+z^6} \quad if \quad x,y,z\neq 0
\\  a\qquad \qquad  else.
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

To prove a function is continuous, we need  $f(x)$ define at $x_0$ (condition 1). We also need to prove $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$ (condition 2).

Question1:
For this question, whatever $a$ value is, this function is not continuous at the given point. I can prove that the limit of $\lim_{x,y,z \to 0}\frac{x^2yz^2}{x^6+y^4+z^6}$ does not exists, thus it's not continuous at the given point. Is there any other alternative way to prove it?

Question 2:
Apart from that, if I have a similar example:

$$
f(x,y,z)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
g(x,y,z) \quad  if \quad x,y,z\neq 0
\\  b\quad \quad \quad \qquad  else.
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

If $\lim_{x,y,z \to 0}g(x,y,z)=k$, where $k$ is a number. Can I say that $b=k$ is the way that make this function continuous?

Comment: Replace (twice) $x,y,z\ne0$ by $(x,y,z)\ne(0,0,0)$ (which is what you really mean), and $x,y,z\to0$ by $(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0).$ Apart from that, I agree with your solutions to the 2 problems.

Answer (score 1):

for 1)
you may try to prove that the $f(x,y,z)$ has partial derivatives that are continuous in $(0,0,0)$, therefore $f$ must be continuous in that point.

2. yes. if $f(0,0,0) = b$,
   and also $\lim_{(x,y,z) \to (0,0,0)} f(x,y,z)=k$,
   so $k$ must be $k=b$ for $f$ to be continuous.